# Divs on the same row in html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Without using HTML Table is there any solution to put 2 divs on different columns in a row and on the same rows, 2 divs on the same column one above another one?

This is an image that explains better:

[image]

I'm using bootstrap, i'm trying to reach this :
[image]

This is what i get now:
[image]

How can i align bottom-top DIV 1 and DIV 2 to be centered if there are on different rows?

At this moment my html grid is like :
[image]

```css
.label {
  font-size: 15px;
}
` #liveChat {
  background-color: #1C3A69;
}
`
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 panel" id="mainDiv">
    <header class="row panel-heading"> <span>Tax</span>Extension.com</header>

    <div id="liveChat" class="row ">

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div id="taxExtensions" class="label col-md-2 leftItems">
            My Tax Extensions
          </div>
          <div id="UpdateAccount" class="label  col-md-1 leftItems ">
            Update Account Info
          </div>
          <div class="label col-md-2 col-md-offset-7 ">
            <div>
              LIVE CHAT
            </div>
            <div>
              Support is Online
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body row" id="mainContent" style="min-height:200px; background-color:aquamarine;">

    </div>

    <footer class="panel-footer row">Footer</footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide a working sample/fiddle?

Comment: are you making a navigation bar?

Comment: @TrulyXax, then make use of bootstrap navbar instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working for a navbar. Then why not use bootstrap navbar component?
Check this out. You can also see it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dfdpxxrx/)

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default sample">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a> -->
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <div class="row right-items text-center">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">LIVE CHAT</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">Support is Online</div>
                </div>
            </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.sample{
    background: #1c3a69;
}

nav{
    color: #fff;
}

.right-items {
     margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple one can be made like this, if the navbar has predefined height

Basically it's just a stack of divs

```css
#div-l{
background-color:red;
}
#div-m{
background-color:blue;
}
#div-r1{
background-color:green;
}
#div-r2{
background-color:grey;
}
.single-stack{
height:50px;
float:left;
width:33%
}
.double-stack{
height:25px;
float:left;
width:33%
}
```

```html
<div id="div-l" class="single-stack">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="div-m" class="single-stack">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="div-r1" class="double-stack">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="div-r2" class="double-stack">&nbsp;</div>
```